# Scroll not working with md-select in angular js

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-material

This is my view code......

```
<md-select aria-label="..." ng-model="topping">
                <md-option>Show All</md-option>
                <md-option>Fit width</md-option>
                <md-option>Full Size</md-option>
                <div style="height: 100px;overflow-y: scroll; border-top: 1px solid #ccc">
                    <md-option>100%</md-option>
                    <md-option>75%</md-option>
                    <md-option>50%</md-option>
                    <md-option>33.33%</md-option>
                    <md-option>25%</md-option>
                    <md-option>12.5%</md-option>
                    <md-option>8.33%</md-option>
                </div>
        </md-select>
```

When I click on scroll bar the drop-down disappears and I am not able to select any option

Comment: Are you sure you can place a `<div>` between the `<md-option>` elements? Can you also check that `topping` corresponds with a variable in your ng-controller?

Comment: Yes, the div inside <md-option>  act as a divider.Also topping corresponds with a variable in my controller

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my `<md-select>` options weren't scrolling. When I put `flex="20"` into `<md-input-container>` it scrolled. Here's my full code:

```js
<md-input-container flex="20">
      <label ng-switch on="nativeLanguage" class="md-subhead">
        <span ng-switch-when="en-US">Change to clip:</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="es">Cambiar a acortar:</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="zh">更改为剪辑:</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="jp">クリップに変更:</span>
        <span ng-switch-default>Change to clip:</span>
      </label>
      <md-select name="selectClip" ng-model="selectClipInMovieWatching">
        <md-option ng-repeat="element in clipArray" ng-value="element">
          Clip: {{element}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```